# Linux: Programatically shutdown or reboot computer from a user-level process

Tags: c, linux, shutdown

How do I programatically trigger a system shutdown or reboot in Linux? Preferably without requiring elevated privileges.

On older releases (e.g. Ubuntu 10.04) I could call HAL's `org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown` or `Reboot` methods using D-Bus. See: http://people.freedesktop.org/~dkukawka/hal-spec-git/hal-spec.html#interface-device-systempower.

However HAL appears to be obsolete, and is not present in Ubuntu 12.10. What is the current best-practice for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ConsoleKit](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit/). Send a `org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop` DBus message to `org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit`. From the command line, that would be something like:

```
dbus-send \
    --system \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit \
    --type=method_call \
    --print-reply \
    --reply-timeout=2000 \
    /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager \
    org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

If the current user is authorized to perform shutdown, then no root privileges are needed.

You can also take a look at the [KShutdown](http://kshutdown.sourceforge.net) utility. It contains source code for different shutdown methods, ranging from ConsoleKit to Gnome and KDE APIs.

Comment: Is there anywhere all these sorts of DBus messaging hacks are actually documented?

Comment: @R.. Sure: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#dbus-reference Note though that DBus is simply the messaging system. The documentation is always in the framework you want to send the messages to.

Comment: I think the major problem with the documentation is that you have to be both well-versed in DBus usage itself *and* the framework you're sending messages to. Would it really hurt them to just document the `dbus-send` commands you need to use along with the framework documentation? It's also often very non-obvious what the full path you're supposed to send the message to is...

Comment: I get `Error org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.NotPrivileged: Not Authorized` when I try this on Ubuntu 12.10. What determines whether a user is authorised to perform the shutdown?

Comment: @NickHutchinson On my system, it's a setting in KDM (KDE Display Manager). I suppose Unity would have some similar setting.

Answer (score 3):

The [`shutdown`](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/shutdown/) command.  However, that requires root privileges on most systems.

Shutdown now:

```
shutdown -h now
```

Restart now:

```
shutdown -r now
```

`man shutdown` for more info.