# Safe reboot linux in C

Tags: c, linux, api, reboot

how can i made a safe reboot like shell command `reboot` from C without exec? The reboot function in reboot.h is not safe. It make no sync and probaly no unmount und safe process termination. What function have the magic parameter?

Bet regards

Comment: I'm betting "many", or "kind".

Comment: You *do* know just about all system commands in Linux is open-source, and have the source available for anyone to study? That means you could find out which package the `reboot` command comes from, find the source and see exactly what it does.

Comment: Why do you want to reboot without any `exec`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
system('reboot')
```

Otherwise, you have [Linux: Programatically shutdown or reboot computer from a user-level process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774312/linux-programatically-shutdown-or-reboot-computer-from-a-user-level-process)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are systems in which reboot is done without properly unmounting partitions, causing filesystem errors. For instance Android is only **forcing** filesystem to mount to read-only (by [issuing](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/system/core/libcutils/android_reboot.c#78) "u" command to *sysrq-trigger*). If you're not focused on performance and you rather want system to be shutdown cleanly, not quickly, then you need to perform following steps:

- Stop main *[init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)* loop. There is no single method to do this and it depends on what exactly *init* implementation your system is using. You need to stop the main *init* loop because you don't want *init* to restart processes that you will start killing in next step.
- Issue "stop" signal to all processes to let them finish their actions
- If "stop" takes too long time, issue "kill" signal to all processes. You don't want to have processes with open files before unmounting.
- Unmount all partitions to read-only
- Ask kernel to shutdown the machine by issuing *reboot* standard call.

All above steps you can do from C-code using calls like [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill), [umount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umount.2.html), [reboot](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html).

As I said before, Android is not a best example in terms of clean shutdown, but you can have a look on example C-code shutdown implementation [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/system/core/libcutils/android_reboot.c#92).

Comment: Since Android 8, filesystems are unmounted before sending `reboot` syscall: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/commit/8d01f63f50fb001f41835a0dab636981f2ba76dd